# how to get findOne current date value in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

`var todayOrderCount = await OrderDetails.find({ "createdAt": {$gte: Date()},status: 2}).count();`

i need data according date choosing count

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: its working now const start = new Date().toDateString();
var todayOrderCount = await OrderDetails.find({ "createdAt": {$gte: start },status: 2}).count();

Answer (score 1):

```
var todayOrderCount = await OrderDetails.find({"createdAt": { $gte: new Date() }, status: 2 }).count();
```

You should use **new** keyword before Date() in order to get date with date type, when you use it without **new** keyword it will return date as a string.
also check **createdAt** type in your db maybe its timestamp in that case use

```
  new Date().getTime()
```